# Display Daylight Saving Time when using simple_form and time-helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form

I am trying to create a drop down with different timezones using the simple_form gem and the timezone helper. This works fine using this bit of code:

```
.tag = f.input :timezone, as: :time_zone
```

The problem is, that the timezone is displayed like so GMT+1 even though, thanks to daylight saving time we are (right now) GMT+2. Any way I can make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DST has a reason only in context of time moment i.e. if you known time moment and timezone you can determine has it DST or not. This input known nothing about your time moment, so it just display default formatted time zone values.

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7297) is discussion about your problem where it described in details.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. Is there any easy way I could wrap this, given that I use e.g. a US-Timezone around there?

Comment: I think if you want to have a deal with DST you can try to build [list of timezones](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/TimeZone/us_zones/class) and format them use server time to determine DST. Then just display them in [select control](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I might reconsider. This will mess up the database entries as well no? Or I would need to convert them back to UTC...

Comment: I think you want to display them with DST, but store time zone name (without DST). In this case you can easy [convert timezone name](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/TimeZone/new/class) to TimeZone object and use this as you wish.